# Exlude a reference from blocking garbage collection of an object in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a List in Java which allows to use the same object at multiple places. (Table rows, so they are not cached multiple times in memory).

Is there a way to tell the garbage collector, that he is allowed to remove object that are only referenced by this List, and nowhere else?

Or is there a better design for sharing objects like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the garbage collector, that he is allowed to remove object that are only referenced by this List, and nowhere else?

Sort of. You want to make it a `List<WeakReference<T>>` or something similar. See the documentation for `WeakReference` and `SoftReference` for details about the degree to which each of them inhibits collection.

Now when you *use* the elements of that list, you'll need to check whether the value within the [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) or [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) has already been collected, so it's not a transparent change - but I think it's what you're looking for.